# В iOS не кликабельны input в попап окне fancybox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ios, fancybox, contact-form7

Обнаружилось, что на iOS устройствах в попап окне Fancybox 3 не кликабельны input поля, т.е. при клике на них ничего не происходит, не понимаю почему, сколько раз использовал Fancybox и плагин Contact form 7 вместе, всегда все работало, а в данном варианте не хочет.

При клике на кнопку "Начать расчет стоимости" в самом конце расчета будет форма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, в css обнаружилось такое

```
.wpcf7-form-control {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```